# C# socket custom string

Tags: c#

I'm sending socket with this function:

```
public static List<Socket> samp = new List<Socket>();

IPHostEntry host = null;
Socket sock;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(serverip);

foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
{
     IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 7777);
     sock = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
     sock.Connect(ipe);
     if (sock.Connected)
     {
          samp.Add(sock);
     }
}
```

samp.Add(sock); sends my ip, for example 127.0.0.1, how can I add string to ip? For example: Nickname:127.0.0.1 ? Thanks in advance! Or how can I send two sockets? For example:
First socket - nickname
Second - ip
Thnx alot

Comment: samp.Add(sock); doesn't send anything, it just adds the socket to a list if its connected, please rephrase the question.

Comment: hmm, really, thanks alot :D